# How can I activate a click event for a checkbox in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am trying to remotely activate a checkbox in Meteor from another point on the page.  For some reason, the checkbox does not trigger the click.  Other jQuery events such as remove() are working.  Below is the code:

```
'click .selectPill': function(e, template) {
    var name = $(e.target).attr('for');
    var input = $(template.find('input[name='+name+']')).trigger('click');
    $(e.target).toggleClass('pillChecked');

}
```

Is there something in Meteor that is preventing this from working...or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: This function doesn't trigger or jQuery isn't working properly?

Comment: Please copy your code to a meteorpad.com

Comment: @RuneJeppesen jquery isnt working properly

Comment: @Davis i realize that but much easier to help if we can see live code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Change` event will do the trick

```
Template.templateName.events({
  'click .selectPill': function(e) {
    var name = $(e.target).attr('for');
    if ($("input[name='+name+']").attr('checked') == 'checked'){
      $("input[name='+name+']").trigger('change').removeAttr('checked');
    }
    else{
      $("input[name='+name+']").trigger('change').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
  },
  'change #input':function(e){
    alert("value changed");
  }
})
```